# Automatically select Try Ubuntu with Live USB

Tags: boot

I'm authoring an Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB stick with a program called Cubic. It takes an Ubuntu iso and lets you make changes in a chroot environment and then write out an ISO.

I would like for the Live USB to boot up and automatically select the "Try Ubuntu" option without showing the choice of Try or Install.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sudo apt remove --purge ubiquity works